# Please can anyone explain the SVG polygon points?

Tags: html, svg

I need to know SVG polygon points, how those works.
Can anyone give clear explanation or other links where I can get clear explanation.

IF possible explain how these polygon points working internally, I mean what algorithem it was using?

```
 <svg height="210" width="500">
  <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198"
  style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:nonzero;" />
</svg>
```

**Update-:**
The main intention behind this question is how polygon taking the points attributes and how it was rendering in the browser as polygon?

Answer (score 45):

The `polygon` takes a list of `points` (ref [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/points)) which are the X and Y coordinates of each pair.

In your example, you have

```
points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198"
```

This is five "corners" starting at (100,10), with a line from there to (40, 198) and so on. The final point joins the first point to make a closed polygon.

The docs tell us:

> Each point is define by a X and a Y coordinate in the user coordinate
> system.

The units are pixels and

> the initial viewport coordinate system (and therefore the initial user
> coordinate system) has its origin at the top/left of the viewport,
> with the positive x-axis pointing towards the right, the positive
> y-axis pointing down

(from [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html))

So, 100, 10 is 100 pixels right and 10 down.

Answer (score 0):

The  element is used to create a graphic that contains at least three sides.
Polygons are made of straight lines, and the shape is "closed" (all the lines connect up).
You can see some examples [here](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_polygon.asp)

Comment: Maky- Thank you for your quick response.
This is not I'm looking for, I'm looking for each point(x and y coordinates) explanation.
Eg: 100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198
in the above co-ordinates what 100,10 denotes, 40,198 denotes like that i need to know each point

Comment: The link returns 404